# Query global temp table on a linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, distributed-transactions

I have seen all of the references on how to query two different tables on two different SQL servers, and I understand how it is to be implemented. However, the command doesn't seem work with temporary tables created with the `##`.

If I write a join on one server, and it references one temp table on that server, and one temp table on the other server, SQL Server assumes that because the `##` is in the command, it automatically looks at the local server's `tempdb`, not the remote one. I also cannot use `OPENROWSET` at this time because the feature has been disabled and I have to get approval to turn it back on.

So my question is there a way that I can reconfigure this command to recognize which `tempdb` to look at?

```
SELECT * 
FROM (##mytemptable1 Demog 
INNER JOIN MyServer.tempdb.dbo.##mytemptable2 PeakInfo ON (Demog.SAMPLE_NO = PeakInfo.SampleNum)  AND  (Demog.JOB_NO = PeakInfo.JobNum) )
ORDER BY PeakInfo.JobNum, PeakInfo.SampleNum,   PeakInfo.Replicate ,PeakInfo.Reinjection ,PeakInfo.PeakNameCustSort
```

Comment: Is the remote temp table created by a separate process, or the same one that's joining them together?

Answer (score 21):

try this to query global temp table from linked server

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(linkedServerName, 'SELECT * FROM ##temp')
```

Comment: I can verify this works, not sure if OP has access to OpenQuery though since OpenRowSet was disabled.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986(v=sql.105).aspx says that the global temp tables are visible only on the specific instance of SQL Server:

> Global temporary tables are visible to any user and any connection
>   after they are created, and are deleted when all users that are
>   referencing the table disconnect from the instance of SQL Server.

Also, any action attempted on the remote global temp table results in a clear error message:

```
SELECT * FROM LinkedServerName.TempDB.dbo.##GLOBTABLE
```

`Database name 'TempDB' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.`

Looks like the answer is no, there's no (easy) way.